# How to format a number to percentage with two decimals using FormatJs Message Syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl, formatjs

Using `react-intl` I have the following message:

```
serviceFee: {
  en: 'Service fee: ({fee, number, percent})',
  ...
},
```

When I call

```
<FormatMessage id="serviceFee" values={{ fee: 0.0625 }} />
```

I expect it to render:

> Service fee: 6.25%

But I get a rounded value:

> Service fee: 6%

How to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's two ways of doing that:

1. You can remove the percent style from the message syntax:

   ```
   serviceFee: 'Service fee: ({fee})'
   ```

   Then send the value with the correct format:

   ```
   <FormatMessage
     id="serviceFee"
     values={{ fee: intl.formatNumber(0.0625, { style: 'percent', maximumFractionDigits: 2 }) }}
   />
   ```

Or

2. Create a custom format that sets the necessary option:

   ```
   const formats = {
     number: {
       percentWith2Decimals: { style: 'percent', maximumFractionDigits: 2 },
     },
   }
   ```

   Add add the formats to your `IntlProvider`:

   ```
   <IntlProvider formats={formats}>...</IntlProvider>
   ```

   Then use the custom format in your message:

   ```
   serviceFee: 'Service fee: ({fee, number, percentWith2Decimals})'
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `minimumFractionDigits={2}}` prop from [documentation](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Components#formattednumber).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FormattedNumber } from "react-intl";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FormattedNumber
        style='percent'
        value={0.0625}
        minimumFractionDigits={2}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The above code renders:

[image: output]

[Codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vnl451o073).

Comment: But I need to use `FormatMessage` because it has text within it and I can't join different strings because the translation changes the place of the number